# Can I return a global variable from Function?

Tags: function, properties

- Declare a global variable named aCar as an object with no properties.
- Declare a function named getTransmission that will return the transmission property of global variable named aCar
- Declare a function named getModel that will return the model property of global variable named aCar

```
<script id="candidateCode">

    var myCar =         
    {
    make : "Honda"
    ,model :"Accord"
    ,year: 2019
    ,transmission: "Automatic"
    }

    var aCar = {};      

    function getCar(aCar) {         
        return {year: 2020};
    }

    function addTransmission(aCar) {
        aCar.transmission ="Automatic";
    }

    function addMakeModel(aCar) {
        aCar.make ="Toyata";
        aCar.model ="Civic";
    }
    

    function getTransmission(aCar) {
        return
    }

    function getModel(aCar) {
        
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var aCar = {};      

    function getCar(aCar) {         
        return {year: 2020};
    }

    function addTransmission(aCar) {
        aCar.transmission ="Automatic";
    }

    function addMakeModel(aCar) {
        aCar.make ="Toyata";
        aCar.model ="Civic";
    }
    

    function getTransmission(aCar) {
        return
    }

    function getModel(aCar) {
        
    }
```